# Magento Commerce Cloud 2.3 Maximum Number of Customer Groups?

Tags: performance, customer-group, magento2-cloud

we are on a Magento Commerce Cloud Pro plan.

For customer pricing in our B2B store, I was wondering if there is any suggestion on how many customer groups I can create without facing issues (performance for example).

I will at least have a number of 8000 customer groups for the start.

Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: yes, 8000 customer group surely hit on performance. are you using any extension?

Comment: no, for customer pricing, I wanted to use the M2 core functionality with different pricing per customer group.

Comment: We are using amasty group cat extension for customer classification but this gives a high hit on performance and some time database got locked due to DB transaction related to this.

Answer (score 0):

Creating many customer groups has a negative impact on the reindex and cache. As you know magento cache pivots also by customer group.

Then we have the reindex problem, the table 'catalog_product_index_price' adds a price row for each customer group, so if you have 1 product and 1.000 customer groups, 1000 rows will be added in the table being totally a scalability problem.

Try not to base your developments on customer groups to avoid these problems.

If you manage magento - enterprise you should know that customer segments exist and that maybe you can solve your casuistry with it.